# Multiple agents with same order number

Tags: anylogic

How to pick up multiple agents with same order number in Anylogic?

For example- my arriving agents have order number in the following order:
A,A,B,C,A,B,C
Then I want 3 agents with order number should be pickup together and move ahead and similarly with B and C.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide some example of what you have tried so that someone can help steer you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to do this. You could batch your agents depending on your order number before pickup or use the pickup condition, e.g. pick all agents up with the same id than the first one in the queue.

See here for the help:

Batch - https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2F_ProcessModeling%2FPickup.html

Pickup - https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2F_ProcessModeling%2FPickup.html

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. But I need to pick up from two different queues. For example say, my  agents are coming order A,A,B,C,A,B,B,C from one queue and from another queue, the agents are coming in order B,A,A,C,B,C,A then total 6 A's should be picked up.

Comment: Should work the same way: (i) do all pickups from the first queue with the pickup condition; (ii) save the order id in the entity (agent), which performed the pickup; (iii) use this saved id to pickup all agents with the matching id at the second queue